# Add a custom show/hide button to admin page in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, custom-controls

I am working on a Django project and I need to add a custom button **show/hide** in the admin page for image files. Depending on the value of the button; the image file will be hidden or shown to the user on the website.

How can I do this ?

Thank You.

**models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    imageSrc = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

**admin.py**

```
class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ['user']
    list_display = ('user', 'imageSrc', 'caption')

admin.site.register(Image, EntryAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do it would be to add something like `display = models.BooleanField()` in your Image model, and then you can filter the displaying of the image either through your view (by not passing the image to the template), or in your template (with a `{% if thisImage.display %} <img src="{{thisImage.imageSrc}}"> {% endif %}`).